# Implementing listener (subscription) in GUI using async extensions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, subscription, async-await

This is the model for 3 layer application with asynchronous response I am trying to use:

- GUI
- Back-end
- Remote Server

GUI:

```
private async void readFloatButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FloatValueLabel.Content = (await srvProtocol.ReadFloat("ReadFloatX")).ToString();
}
```

Back-end (uses internal variables *binReader* and *connection*)

```
public Task<float> ReadFloat(string cmd)
 {
   var tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<float>();
   var floatTask = tcs1.Task;    
   RegisterResponse(cmd, 
                     () =>
                     tcs1.SetResult(_binReader.ReadSingle());
                    );
   // We are ready: now send request to server(assuming that this is a quick operation)
   connection.Send(cmd); 
   return floatTask;
 }
```

Here RegisterResponse adds a < Key, Action > pair to some thread-safe dictionary.
Another worker thread reads from the network stream messages (message headers) and calls actions according to the string cmd found in the message header.

Now the question:

- is it possible to reach same level of conciseness when I will need to subscribe GUI elements for periodic updates (not a single callback)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just take what you have and put in into a loop, e.g.:

```
private async void StartReading()
{
  while (true)
  {
    FloatValueLabel.Content = (await srvProtocol.ReadFloat("ReadFloatX")).ToString();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Though I personally am not fond of the "infinite async" loop. The only way to stop the loop is to throw an exception (error or cancellation).

The [Rx library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) is more suited for subscriptions. It allows a high level of 
"conciseness," but has a steeper learning curve.

You can also wrap all the subscription logic into a Model/ViewModel. This particularly makes sense when dealing with "updating" the same conceptual value. In that case, `StartReading` would be a method on your Model/ViewModel. It would use `async` (for the infinite async loop) or `ObserveOn` (for Rx) to bring the updates onto the UI thread, and then use the standard `INotifyPropertyChanged` / `ObservableCollection` to update the UI indirectly.

Comment: Thanks. This kind of loop is a possible solution, but you are right: I indeed would take it only as temporary workaround. 
I will look into Rx, but I am starting to wonder whether the TPL DataFlow can provide the solution coherent to the style in my sample.

Comment: Stephen, after diving into Rx, I agree that your answer is indeed complete and provides the most coherent answer to my question.
Thanks!